# database 101 problems with asp.net mvc website

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a simple bunch of problems and with a ridiculous timeline and I just ate away over an hour trying to get the database up and running.

I have with me an asp.net-mvc project which has a bunch of Models in code-first. Was given over to me my someone. He used MvcScaffolding and I had nice repositories for each Model and and forms for CRUD already.

**The problem** is the data is currently temporary. Now I added a connection string into the web.config like Eriks [article says here.](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/04/saving-images-to-sql-server-compact.html) It created an sdf database. But I cannot open this in VS or Sql Mgmt Stdio. It gives me :

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

When I also add a database from within visual studio server explorer and/or the solution explorer gives me the same thing.

I also tried creating the Db with some schema in SQL Mgm Studio but when I try to create and EF model in VS it says the same thing!

Is there any other quicker option I have now? I tried SQL Server, but thats always a pain to connect to across my other co-workers.

Is there a library/tool that can take my Models and create some schema with an entity framework model that I can edit with the designer? I can't seem to envision which models/tables go where and there aren't any relationships between them yet.

I'm using Entity-Framework4 and VS2010 with asp.net-mvc3/razor.

Comment: Is this related? [mapping with entity framework code first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858846/mapping-with-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: @Peter nope. since there are no mappings at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me google that for you: http://hestia.typepad.com/flatlander/2010/08/fixing-the-server-explorer-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-error.html

Comment: Hey thanks erik. I did look at that msdn articles about creating a new user account. This may sound silly but is it creating a new windows a/c. I just thought that solution was vague!. Anyway, the article you pointed is about removing a dud connection string. I instead wanted to create the EF (edmx) model since I've never done code first.

Comment: +1 Tell me tho, currently, with just the code models and a DBContext, the data is getting stored somewhere temporarily.  Where is that? Is the Db getting created and then deleted?